# WPF "cannot locate resource"

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have just branched over to the WPF loop from WinForms and I'm having a problem loading some of my controls when I roll the software into production. Locally on my machine everything works fine but when rolled out to a client machine I get the following error:

NumericalUpDown..ctor() - Cannot locate resource 'wpfcontrols/numericalupdown.xaml'

The control is in a class library I created. If I use the control on the main window it works fine but when I try and access it from a new window I create at run time it errors. All the required assemblies are there (they must be or it wouldn't work locally) and there's no other external resources other then the default WPF controls. I've been banging my head against the wall for the past 2 hours, any help is greatly appreciated,

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a copy of the assembly in your output bin, but the copy that you distributed does not have a copy of it.  In the publishing options, did you set the assembly to be copied with the distribution package?  Is there a copy of the .dll next to the .exe file?

Comment: The referenced assembly is defiantly there. I have created a new solution and copied all the code over and it seems to work now. I think it may have been a problem from when I re-factored one of the projects names.

Comment: "defiantly" or "definitely" haha!  I'm glad it's working now.  That type of mysterious problems happens sometimes.